# populating array of objects using ref which is also an array of object mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
var wordsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    words: [{
        w_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
        meaning: String,
        synonyms: String,
        sentence: String
    }]
```

})

```
var knownWordsSchema = new Schema({
kWords:[{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Words"
}]
```

})

**How do i populate KnownWords, as the objectId i need to populate it is inside and array of object**

For example: if knownWords has an id "a" and words is `words: [{
w_id: a,
name: "h",
meaning: "h",
synonyms: "h",
sentence: "h"
}]`

i want knownWords to have an object as `{
name: "h",
meaning: "h",
synonyms: "h",
sentence: "h"
}`

** P.s: I am a beginner so i don't know how to put it into words.**

Answer (score 0):

KnownWordSchema is not properly formatted.

```
let knownWordsSchema = new Schema({
kWords:[{
    words:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Words"
    }
}]
```

now somewhere in your code:

```
KnownWords.findOne({words:req.params.w_id})
.populate('words',['name','meaning','synonyms','sentence'])
```

[populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method will populate specified fields.

Comment: Thanks for answering... but i want KnownWords as an array of object so findOne query would only give me one object. how do i populate the whole array ?

Comment: knownWords is already an array of objects because of the square brackets `[ ]`. When you use them, you declare an array. Now, to add new object to this array, `kwords.words.push(newWord)` then `kwords.save(done)` . newWord is the word object you get from a request or any other way.

Comment: Yes it is an array of objects, but the array only contains objectId and i want to populate the array of object(objectId) as a whole and then send the entire array to another webpage. As you said i can do findOne query but it will as it says find one id and populate it whereas i want the whole array to be populated.. Please help ....

Comment: For that, use find method with empty object. Like this:             `knownWords.find({ },(err,words )=>{ //you have all your words here})`

Comment: I did that but its returning an empty array. Can you look at the  https://github.com/anil-maharjan/Vocabuildary  repository  and help me? My code is a mess so plz don't judge me . :'(